# How do I suppress warnings using devenv build?

Tags: vb.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I am using this command to build my solution using x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2022:

```
devenv D:\Dev\Projects\wscc.sln /build "Release|x86"
```

How do I disable / suppress warnings being output in the console?

Comment: Have you tried to disable warnings in property settings or use  `vbc -nowarn` instead? I tested it on my side and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I define `Unused local variable` in my vb project in VS 2022 for test and it outputs the warning 42024 in my console after building with `devenv solution.sln /build Release`   as shown in the picture below.

[image]

From [devenv doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/build-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022), there’s no supported parameter like `NoWarn` to suppress warnings .But i find here’re 2 workarounds to disable / suppress warnings being output in the console.

1 The Compile tab of the Project Designer page allows you to turn warnings on and off. Select the Disable All Warnings check box to disable all warnings .Path:right click project and select Properties.
[image]

Or you can select specified waring type(e.g: Unused local variable) and set it to `None` that will disable `Unused local variable` warning being output in console. For more information, please refer to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/compile-page-project-designer-visual-basic?view=vs-2022)

Or In Solution Explorer, open the right-click or shortcut menu for the project, and then choose Edit .vbproj. add one or more warning numbers as the value of the  element.

For example(with two compiler warnings suppressed)

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">    
  <NoWarn>42022,42024 </NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

2 use `-nowarn` For example: The following code compiles Program.vb and does not display any warnings.
[image]